# How to style a suggestion box so it doesn't push the elements below it?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have this location input field with location autocomplete using mapbox. What's happening is that every time the suggestions appears, it pushes the other items below it. As in this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RY88.png).

```
<input className="w-full bg-gray-100 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg focus:outline-none"
  {...location}
  type="text"
></input>

       {location.suggestions?.length > 0 && (
          <div className="relative px-2 py-4">
            {location.suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              return (
                <p className="cursor-pointer"
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => {
                    location.setValue(suggestion.place_name);
                    location.setSuggestions([]);
                    setValue("location", suggestion.place_name);
                  }}
                >
                  {suggestion.place_name}
                </p>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )}
```

It pushing the elements below it is to be expected with relative positioning, however, when I use absolute positioning, it just goes to the top of the page which I'm guessing is because by default, absolute is set with `top: 0px`. I have other input elements on top of it so I'm not sure how to estimate how many pixels I should set the top to or if its even a good practice to hard-code it. You can see what it looks like using absolute positioning in this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSRE4.png).

Comment: Can you post the HTML rendered to the browser, rather than the React component that produces the HTML? This will allow you to get better solutions tailored to the results you're working with, rather than generic examples and guesses. Please see the guidance we have on "*[mcve]*" code, and maybe take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `position` to `relative` for the container and then add a `background-color` to the dropdown:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.input-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.input-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.input-dropdown > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="input-dropdown">
    <div>
      Element 1
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 2
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 3
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 1
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 2
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 3
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 1
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 2
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 3
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 1
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 2
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 3
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 1
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 2
    </div>
        <div>
      Element 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit vero, fugit officia beatae tempora nesciunt provident doloremque. Omnis voluptas hic neque incidunt, iste nihil corrupti, odit reprehenderit cum adipisci error!
</p>
```

You can find more infos here: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/